# Why do Trackbacks/Pingbacks not appear below my posts/pages?

Tags: themes, pingbacks

My wordpress required me to check some Trackbacks and I checked and accepted them. They are listed in the comment administration and I activated "allow Trackbacks/Pingbacks on this page" on the relevant articles and pages.

But they do not appear below the relevant posts and pages. Comments are displayed, but not Trackbacks. Does this maybe result from me using the "SimpleX" Theme? Can I somehow modify it to display them? Or did I just miss a checkbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On what posts did you expect a trackback? SimpleX should support trackbacks, [but displays them in a separate box](http://www.wpshoppe.com/2009/01/25/trackbacks-comments/).

Comment: I expect some trackbacks on this page: http://hinek.de/pen-paper-rollenspiele/serenity-rpg/

Comment: @Hinek: This page (and other pages on your site) seem to show no comments at all, and no comment form. Could you try (re-)opening comments, leave one yourself (maybe as a logged-out user), and see whether that appears? Does your `page.php` template include the comments template?

Comment: Ok, comments_template('', true); was missing ... I put it in and it did the job. THANKS!!!